# How to update a table using a .sql file without deleting the data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database and a file that should replace a field that is from 0 to 1, but only according to a specific product ID. when i load the file to replace in the database it deletes/remove the other fields as well.

In case, I had a database and did a massive field update: subtract to 0 , which was a stupid error, i decided to revert from 1 to backup, however when i load the file something very bad happens it deletes all other fields and replaces model and subtract.

```
UPDATE `product` (`id`, `model`, `subtract`) VALUES
(42, 'Product 15', 1),
(51, ' LSE5MGC', 1),
(52, 'LNSBGV8', 1),
(53, 'LOTEPEB', 1),
(54, 'LFRON8O', 1),
(55, 'LA51T52', 1),
(56, 'LWCH79V', 1),
(57, ' LYLTF8N', 1),
(58, 'argan01', 1),



INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `model`, `sku`, `upc`, `ean`, `jan`, `isbn`, `mpn`, `location`, `quantity`, `stock_status_id`, `image`, `manufacturer_id`, `shipping`, `price`, `points`, `tax_class_id`, `date_available`, `weight`, `weight_class_id`, `length`, `width`, `height`, `length_class_id`, `subtract`, `minimum`, `sort_order`, `status`, `viewed`, `date_added`, `date_modified`, `referral`, `partner`, `import_batch`, `meta_robots`, `seo_canonical`, `sets`) VALUES
(42, 'Product 15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 988, 7, 'images/product.jpg', 11, 1, 13.9000, 0, 0, '2009-02-04', 0.00000000, 1, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 1, 0, 1, 10, 1, 1108, '2009-02-03 21:07:37', '2020-12-28 11:57:43', '', '', NULL, '', '', 0),
(51, ' LSE5MGC', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 6, 'images/product.jpg', 17, 1, 16.0000, 0, 0, '2015-09-23', 0.00000000, 1, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 104, '2015-09-23 11:22:52', '2020-05-07 11:07:31', '', '', NULL, '', '', 0),
(52, 'LNSBGV8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 5, 'images/product.jpg', 0, 1, 29.0000, 0, 0, '2015-09-23', 0.00000000, 1, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-09-23 11:41:34', '2019-09-18 09:51:07', '', '', NULL, '', '', 0),
```

And these are the other fields, after I make an insert and they are deleted.

Comment: That's not correct `UPDATE` syntax. `UPDATE` doesn't use `VALUES` lists.

Comment: Which are you using, MySQL or SQLIte? Please remove the other tag. And `mysqli` is a PHP library, it has nothing to do with `.sql` files.

Answer (score 1):

You would need multiple UPDATE statements -

```
UPDATE product SET subtract = 1 WHERE id = 42; -- assuming id is your primary key
UPDATE product SET subtract = 1 WHERE id = 51;
-- and so on for other ids too
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the file into a table (say a temp table).  Then run an update like this:

```
update product p join
       table_file f
       on p.id = f.id
    set p.subtract = 1;
```

Or, combine all the ids into a single list and write a query like:

```
update prodct p
    set subtract = 1
    where id in ( . . . );
```